# Mystery Phototube connector

Tags: identification, connector

Can someone identify the type of connector this is and tell me its proper name?

[image: Side View]

[image: Top View]

Comment: Looks to me like it's just a tube socket. Weirdly high number of pins, but maybe that's normal for phototubes.

Comment: Have a look at these guys for Photomultiplier tubes / bases. https://www.sphere.bc.ca/test/photo-tubes.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question.

It is a rough guide of how to find such a socket.

I did an image search for `19 pin nixie socket` because I am aware that nixie tubes have a lot of pins.

One image of interest shows that you could make your own socket.

[image]

A review of the other images yielded a 17 pin socket named B17A.

Your socket has 19 pins, so an image search for `B19A socket` yields https://duckduckgo.com/?q=b19a+socket&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Here is one such image.

[image]

EDIT: One webpage has a module with a circuit.  The module is called `voltage divider`.

[image]

Comment: https://aditelectrontubes.com/products/sockets